# Firebase Update single field by adding to its value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update data from one collection based on data from another.

For example, I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
        .then(function(doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            //Log initial doc
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            
            //Work out sold value based on whats in DB already and what just sold
            // by adding entryTicketNumber to ticketsold 
           const soldValue = doc.data().ticketsold + element.entryTicketNumber;

            //Log out to console to make sure change took place 
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

            //Push update to db
            doc.ref.update({ticketsold: soldValue})
          }
```

The console.logs work fine but the field change isn't. Am I going down the wrong path completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.data()` returns a new copy of the document data with every call.  That's why it's a method call and not a property.  If you change objects in one copy, they won't be seen in other copies.  In fact, you are never even really changing the data at all, and you don't even need to.  Just do this:

```
const data = doc.data();
console.log("Document data:", data);
const soldValue = data.ticketsold + element.entryTicketNumber;
doc.ref.update({ticketsold: soldValue})  // you should catch errors here
```

If you want to see the new values later, you can get() the same document again.  If you need to remember the changed object, just retain `data` somewhere, and be sure to actually modify its properties:

```
data.ticketsold += element.entryTicketNumber;
```

Comment: Yet again Doug, thank you ya genius. Sending you a virtual pint!